# Access Object item within array

Tags: php, arrays, object

How would i go about echoing/printing one of the items in the object within this array?

`$msgs = ['errors'=> array, 'created' => object];`

for example, `var_dump($msgs[1]->name);` produces the following errors

`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications......`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications.....`

and everything else i have tried produces the same and/or similar errors

```
Array
(
[errors] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [location] => 
        [photo1] => 
        [photo2] => 
    )

[created] => Levels Object
    (
        [errors] => ActiveRecord\Errors Object
            (
                [model:ActiveRecord\Errors:private] => 
                [errors:ActiveRecord\Errors:private] => 
            )

        [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 156
                [placement] => 
                [status] => 1
                [name] => kjkj
                [location] => kjj
                [date] => 
                [icon] => 
                [photo1] => kkjkj
                [photo2] => jkjkj
                [photo3] => 
            )

        [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
        [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
        [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var_dump($msgs['errors']->name);
```

Comment: Awesome, could swear that i had tried that already.... Apparently not. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

try ,

`var_dump($msgs['errors']['name']);`

Comment: Have tried that as well, produces the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Levels as array in`

Comment: Have also tried to set the object to an array before adding it to the `$msgs` array; however, that produces undefined index errors